# Assign JQuery validator to global scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

JS get JQquery validator  to global scope to show custom error message

```
 vldtr = {};
 $(function(){
 editTweetvldtr = $("#frm-update-tweet").validate({
            rules: {
                    ....
            },

            messages: {
                  ....
            }
        });

console.log(vldtr); //return obj
});

console.log(vldtr); //return {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is :  assign to window obj

thanks @Schlaus and @Tushar  for your help

```
$(function(){
window.editTweetvldtr = $("#frm-update-tweet").validate({
        rules: {
                ....
        },

        messages: {
              ....
        }
    });

  });

console.log( window.editTweetvldtr  ); //return  the obj
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not initializing your variable with `var`:

```
 var vldtr = {};
 $(function(){
 editTweetvldtr = $("#frm-update-tweet").validate({
            rules: {
                    ....
            },

            messages: {
                  ....
            }
        });

console.log(vldtr); //return obj
});

console.log(vldtr); //return {}
```

The scope in which a variable is first declared with var is the outermost scope in which it is accessible. Doing `var vldtr = {}` outside of all functions, event document.ready, will make it globally accessible.

Global variables are bad and very error prone, but that's how you do it.

To further demonstrate:

```
var a = true;
var b = true;
$(function() {
    var a = false; // this a is no longer the same we declared before
    b = false;     // this is still the same b
});
console.log(a); // true
console.log(b); // false
```

Comment: it does not work the log : {} then obj as if it work in another thread

Comment: @Helal I'm sorry, then the problem must be somewhere else than in the code you posted. Are you sure you're not modifying the object somewhere else? Also remember that javascript objects are always passed by reference.